# At @ sign in property of dynamic object

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml-parsing

Im parsing a XML document

```
      <book id="bk102">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
......
.....
.....
       </book>
```

to Json and from Json to a dynamic object like this.

```
   string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml);
        dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonText);
        var catalog = dyn.catalog;
```

It works an i can get the child elements like
book.author

however when i watch the dynamic object in visual studio i see that the XML elements attribute "id" has been parsed into a property called @id. But i cant access it either with book.id or book.@id. None of them seem to exist.

How is @id properties accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, [`@` is a special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).

In order to access properties named with `@` at the beginning, you can use an indexer, e.g.:

```
var id = ((IDictionary<string, object>)book)["@id"];
```